# Best way to overlay a view on a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

Imagine you have an activity with one fragment and you one to overlay a view (say a TextView) on it sometimes in the app.

There is at least two ways to do so:

1- write a fragment with just that textview and add/remove it via getFragmentManager.

2- modifing activity layout using `merge` tag to have a fragment and textview and then manipulate the visibility of textview in the code.

Which is the best way?